# I can not select a project in Google Developers enable google service page

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin, google-authentication

I am trying to enable Google Sign-In and configure it. But I have truble when I I am trying to select my App that was created in Firebase I got message

> Visit the Firebase console to manage Google services for this project.

And when I select My App from list  opens Firebase console, but I can not enable Google Sign-In and configure in Firebase console.

It's seems I am do something wrong, please tell me the right way[image]

Comment: Ahmm. Are you trying to do a different *enabling* from what you could do in the Authentication > Sign-in Methods part of the Firebase Console? ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj7Or.png))

Comment: @AL. Yes I did it.

Comment: Cool. Are you looking for any other details?

Comment: @AL. I am add all things(sha1-get correct) to project to firebase, but I am getting error in log You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE.

Comment: I suggest updating your post for better visibility.

Comment: @AL. I saw several answers in SO but they not suitable for my situation

Comment: have you found the solution?